# Converting Table Into Text File in MySQL and appending further changes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a log table, where the changes made in remaining tables will be logged. Since it becomes too large to maintain, I thought of dumping the log_table entries into a file once the table reaches a particular row count. I came across a problem, I need the new dumps I make to get appended automatically into the existing dump file. I need a solution for this issue.

Currently I use `SELECT * FROM log_table INTO OUTFILE 'data.txt';` for dumping.

Comment: Please clarify why it is too big? Are queries timing out? Where is the speed issue manifesting itself? For example you cannot query the table or the table is slow to insert...

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
mysql -e "SELECT * FROM log_table" >> data.txt
```

For more information, [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can dump the table using mysqldump command and append it in a file

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword <dbname> log_table >> data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some clients like [SQLyog](https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list) or navicat to dump on the existing file.